# Fixed conditions on outer joins

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

this is not a real example, it is something that has been bugging me for some time, and I'd be very thankful to anyone who can explain this behavior.

I have these two tables

```
MYTABLE1
ID  TYPE    NAME 
1   1       typea
2   2       typea
3   3       typea
4   4       typeb
5   5       typeb
6   6       typeb
7   7       typec
8   8       typec
9   9       typec
10  10      typed

MYTYPE
ID  NAME    DESCRIPTION
1   typea   typea with desc
2   typea   
3   typea   TYPE
4   typeb   typeb with desc
5   typeb   
6   typeb   TYPE
7   typec   typec with desc
8   typec   
9   typec   TYPE
```

I'd like to have a sql that returns rows from both tables (mytable1 a, mytype b) where

a) MYTABLE1.type = MYTYPE.ID and MYTYPE.description='TYPE'

b) MYTABLE1.type is not in MYTYPE.id

```
a.id    a.type  a.name  b.id    b.name  b.description
3       3       typea   3       typea   TYPE
6       6       typeb   6       typeb   TYPE
9       9       typec   9       typec   TYPE
10      10      typed   null    null    null
```

I have tried this statements with no success. I want a solution that uses outer joins, not unions or nested selects.

For the example, I am using Oracle outer join syntax but I think the same result can be achieved by using standard syntax and putting the condition a) inside the ON clause or b)in the where clause

What I'd like is to understand the "strange" behaviour of them, and try to find one that works for the example provided.
Most strange for me it is SQL2. I am not writing the results of the queries, to keep the question shorter, but I can provide them if needed.

### SQL1

```
select * 
from 
  mytable1 a,
  mytype b
where
  a.type=b.id(+)
  and b.description ='TYPE'
order by a.id
```

### SQL2

```
select * 
from 
  mytable1 a,
  mytype b
where
  a.type=b.id(+)
  and b.description(+) ='TYPE'
order by a.id
```

### SQL3

```
select * 
from 
  mytable1 a,
  mytype b
where
  a.type=b.id(+)
  and (b.description ='TYPE' or b.description is null)
order by a.id
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: if you are using (+) to perform outer join in oracle , then you need to add this operator to all columns that join.

Comment: implicit joins are a SQL antipattern

Comment: In SQl Server the =+ join has been delivering inconsistent results for more than ten years (It even tells you that in Books Online for SQl Server 2000). It should under no circumstances ever be used. Implict joins are are a horrible coding practice that was replaced 20 years ago. Why are you still using them. Would you use C# code that was replaced ten years ago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop using old Cartesian product syntax.  `JOIN` syntax is the ANSI-92 standard.  20 years should be enough to be considered stable...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable1    a
LEFT JOIN
  myType      b
    ON b.id = a.type
WHERE
     b.description = 'TYPE'
  OR b.id IS NULL
```

*NOTE:* I did have `b.description IS NULL` but, as far as I recall, ORACLE treats 0 length strings as NULL.  Therefore it is better to test the `id` field for a case of *No Join*.

Comment: that will return some false hits because some of the description values in mytype are null even before the outer join.  should use "or b.id is null" instead

Comment: @ConradFrix - Then how do you filter out rows 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 and 8 from `myTable`?

Comment: @Dems you might as well include that oracle even recommends dropping that syntax. From the [Oracle Doc on Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm) *"Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax:"*

Comment: @btilly - Please could you elaborate on how this does not give the example results in the question?  Rows 1-9 join on the myType table, row 10 doesn't join but is kept as it is a LEFT JOIN.  Then the WHERE clause filters out row 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 and leaves rows 3, 6, 9 and 10.  Exactly as in the example.  If this is somehow incorrect, please would you elaborate with examples, etc?

Comment: @Dems I cannot test it right now, as I don't have access to the database. But would it be the same result if you set the where clause inside the ON clause? [ ON b.id=a.type and (b.description='TYPE' or b.id is null) ]. Maybe this is also not recommended?

Comment: @richardtz the way that @Dems' query is written, It's saying get the records from MyTable1 and also the matching records in MyType. From that include only results where there's either no matching record in MyType or the MyType Descirption is "TYPE". The way I and others suggested doing it would be get *All the records in MyTable1* and also  the records in MyType if the Description is type. Note: `or b.id is null` never makes sense in a Join condition because it will always be false. If it was null it wouldn't fulfill b.id = a.type

Comment: @richardtz [here's a sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eea3a/6) showing both SQL statements and how they behave. You'll need to scroll down

Comment: @everyone, thanks a lot for your answers. I understand it now. It is also important setting the 'is null' condition in the id field instead of the varchar one.